# How to use a Symfony2 Service Container for FOS-UserManager

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, fosuserbundle

my Problem is I´m a Symfony Noobie.

I have the FOSUserBundle and I want simply to access UserManager with this code.

```
$userManager = $container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
```

But it does´t work. My error message is:

[image]

I tried to look weather the service is declared or not with the console commando:
php app/console container:debug but the service 'fos_user.user_manager' is declared/registered.

Is it possible that I forgot something with service container?

Greetings 
Michael

PS: here is my full code of the controller class:

```
    <?php

namespace Main\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/listProfile")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function listProfileAction()
    {
       $user = $container->get('fos_user.user_manager');


        return array('user' => $user);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the class property "container" using `$this->container` rather than a local variable which you are calling at the moment.

The next problem will be that you are just calling the user manager rather than the actual user.

To get the current user you should use...

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

**ALSO**

As you are extending `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` you could also use `$this->get('something.something')` but this is just a shortcut to the `$this->container->get('something.something')` method (see: [Controller source](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php#L265-L276)). `$this->get()` is not available when extending `ContainerAware`.

For some reason I went code `sample` crazy....